# GitHub compare view for current versions of branches

Tags: git, github, branch

Is there a way to use GitHub's "compare view" to view the diff between the *current* versions of two branches?  (That is, to view the same diff that you would get if you did `git diff <a-branch> <another-branch>`.)

I have made a small example [here](https://github.com/akenney/compare-view-test/).  There are two branches: "master" and "other-branch".  If I do `git diff master..other-branch`, this is the diff:

```
diff --git a/README.md b/README.md
index 495cc9f..3d2c3a0 100644
--- a/README.md
+++ b/README.md
@@ -1 +1,3 @@
 Hello there!
+
+This is a commit to the "other-branch" branch.
```

You can see from that diff that the difference between the "master" branch and the "other-branch" branch is the addition of one blank line and one line of text, and there are no deletions.

However, if I try to use GitHub compare view (https://github.com/akenney/compare-view-test/compare/other-branch or https://github.com/akenney/compare-view-test/compare/master...other-branch), it shows this diff:

```
-This is a commit to the master branch.
+Hello there!
+
+This is a commit to the "other-branch" branch.
```

It is comparing the "other-branch" branch with an old version of the "master" branch, not with the current version.  The same thing happens even if I specify the particular commits to compare (https://github.com/akenney/compare-view-test/compare/8ed0d53...e4470ec) - the diff that it's showing is not the diff between those two commits.

Comment: You now (Sept. 2018) can use GitHub's "compare view" to view the diff between the current versions of two branches. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52487331/6309).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

GitHub only supports the triple dots (`...`) range shortcut specification.

From the **[git diff documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff)**:

> **git diff [--options] .. [--] […]**
>
> This is synonymous to the previous form. If  on one side is omitted,
>   it will have the same effect as using HEAD instead.
>
> **git diff [--options] ... [--] […]**
>
> This form is to view the changes on the branch containing and up to the second , starting at a common ancestor of both . "git diff A...B" is equivalent to "git diff $(git-merge-base A B) B". You can omit any one of , which has the same effect as using HEAD instead.

Comment: Okay ... so the answer to the question is no.  Oh well.  Thanks.  I didn't know that that's what the three-dots meant, and I'm not sure why GitHub would not support the normal two-dots type of diff.

Comment: @Avril , I did not understand this answer. Is it possible to make github comparing the latest versions of two branches? and how to do it?

Comment: This answer is talking about `git` rather than `GitHub`, which is what the op was asking.

Answer (score 3):

GitHub now ([Sept. 2018](https://blog.github.com/changelog/2018-09-18-two-dot-comparison/), 4 years later) explicitly supports "[Three-dot and two-dot Git diff comparisons](https://help.github.com/articles/about-comparing-branches-in-pull-requests/#three-dot-and-two-dot-git-diff-comparisons)".

The URL https://github.com/github/linguist/compare/c3a414e..faf7c6 will display:

[image: direct two-dots diff]

The message is:

```
This is a direct comparison between two commits made in this repository or its related forks
```

> Now you can easily see the differences between two commits **without comparing from their common merge base commit like a three dot comparison would**.