# GitHub API: "compare two commits" unclear

Tags: git, github, github-api

## Context

I'm making a tool which uses the GitHub API ([Useful Forks](https://github.com/useful-forks/useful-forks.github.io)). I'm currently trying to understand the behavior I'm seeing with the `compare 2 commits` api. I've gone through the following reading material:

1. [GitHub API `compare 2 commits` documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/repos#compare-two-commits)
2. StackOverflow question #1: [GitHub API - how to compare 2 commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26925312/github-api-how-to-compare-2-commits)
3. StackOverflow question #2: [Github Comparison View for 2 branches is incorrect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32570825/github-comparison-view-for-2-branches-is-incorrect)

But I'm still puzzled...

## Problem

Reproducible steps:

1. Confirm that this parent repository exists: https://github.com/yellowstonegames/SquidLib/network/members
2. Confirm that this is one of its forks: https://github.com/manderin87/SquidLib
3. Confirm that GitHub acknowledges that it's both `behind` and `ahead` of the parent repo:
   [image: commit counts]
4. Confirm that calling the GitHub API to compare the parent and the fork's `master` branch somehow doesn't seem to work: https://api.github.com/repos/yellowstonegames/SquidLib/compare/master...manderin87:master

The response is:

```
{
  "message": "No common ancestor between master and manderin87:master.",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#compare-two-commits"
}
```

I'm not sure I understand if this is the expected behavior or not. (And where could I find a list of all the possible error messages and what triggers them for that particular endpoint?)

## Question

How am I supposed to obtain the numbers given in the screenshot above? (`ahead` and `behind`)

#### Extra question

I find it suspicious that *all* the forks for which this API call I'm making doesn't return an error have *exactly* 1379 commits behind the original repo. You can see that through my tool: https://useful-forks.github.io/?repository=yellowstonegames/SquidLib

[image: confusing results]

Once again, this possibly goes toward my lack of understanding of what this api call is supposed to be returning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How many commits are there in the history of `master` for this specific repo ?

The elements you describe could be coherent with a bulk rewriting of the history of the original repo (a `git filter-branch` operation for example).

Check the sha1 for the first commit in the original repo and in one of its forks, for example.

---

Using local git commands : you can use `git rev-list --count a..b` (resp `b..a`) to see how many commits `b` is ahead (resp behind) of `a`.

`a..b` works even if `a` and `b` have no common history.

`git rev-list a...b` on the other hand searches for a merge base between `a` and `b`, and will fail if there isn't one.

I don't know exactly what API to use to match `git rev-list a..b`, perhaps "List commits" (referred to in the doc you linked) would allow it.

Comment: I can now confirm that the original repository did indeed resort to using `git filter-branch`. Nice catch.